# Debian Firewall will not forward traffic from interface x to tun0

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall, routing

I want to have a debian system working as a router with openvpn traffic, where all traffic on interface x should be forwarded to openvpn interface y.

Following pic shows my network setup, more or less working:
[Network setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQfnV.png)

Iptables roules (active):

```
#!/bin/bash

iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

#iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -o ens19 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -o ens19 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens19 -j ACCEPT

#iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens19 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o ens19 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -m state --state New,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A FORWARD -i ens19 -j ACCEPT

#iptables -t nat -s 192.168.1.0/24 -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
#iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables/rules.v4

exit
```

Forwarding roules:
cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep -v '#'

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

The setup is active, but no traffic is forwarded.

Checked with

```
ping web.de -I ens18    # (Network interface with route to "normal" router.) -> Working
ping web.de -I ens19    # (Network interface with firewall-rule forwarding to tun0.) -> Not working, but getting ip information of "web.de"
ping web.de -I tun0     # (Network interface by openvpn.) -> Working
```

My guess: NAT works, but not forwarding ens19 to tun0.

I found and read many many forums here and on other sites where people discuss the same idea. They just seem to not work for me. Strange :(

`iptables-save`

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [40976:12561334]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [32894:54259570]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [32983:2879147]
-A INPUT -i tun0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ens19 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o ens19 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jan  9 ...
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue Jan  9 ...
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [63033:10635529]
:INPUT ACCEPT [6276:710107]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1569:103282]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1156:77777]
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

What am I missing so that traffic forwarding ens19 -> tun0 should be working? Any help would be great. Thanks

> `ip link; ip -4 -br addr; ip route; ip rule`

[result: `ip link; ip -4 -br addr; ip route; ip rule`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVlXl.png)

Comment: Usual misconception. One has to remember that iptables doesn't route. Telling iptables that the flow between the left side and the vpn is allowed, and if such flow happens it will be NAT-ed, doesn't magically make it happen as allowed. That's the routing part. iptables and NAT can sometimes interact with routing, but never in the **POST**ROUTING part. Can you give as text your network state/setup once the VPN is up? `ip link; ip -4 -br addr; ip route; ip rule`.

Comment: offtopic on serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com instead due non businesses relationship

Comment: Thx @A.B & @ djdomi. One idea -> multiple ways required: I know. Well, routing is setup and activated (hopefully. Results may show "no"), discriped in question. Maybe u mean something different?

Comment: @A.B Postrouting -> nat. Well in most forums on the internet (stackoverflow, debian.org ...) exactly that cmd with iptables is discriped as one of important targets and even my old setup worked that way (But with other networks). Are they all wrong or do I misunderstand?

Comment: `ip link; ip -4 -br addr; ip route; ip rule` -> Yes, updated. (2nd network is deactivated for test issues. Should work as well.)